# Does vuetify to prop behave as router-link or html anchor?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm currently using Vuetify v2 and gonna change all my `nuxt-link` to `<a href></a>` so I was wondering what should i do about vuetify `to` prop ? leave them be or change them to anchor too?

```js
<template>
  <v-card to="/mypage" />
  <!-- OR
  <v-btn to="/">home</v-btn>
  -->
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By providing the `to` prop to routable components like buttons and cards they behaves like `router-link` or `nuxt-link` which will be rendered as anchor elements `<a href="" ...`

please check the [`to` prop docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#props-to) for `v-btn` component  and [`to` api doc](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#to) in router-link :

```
<!-- literal string -->
<router-link to="home">Home</router-link>
<!-- renders to -->
<a href="home">Home</a>
```